# Firebase authentication email retrieve in android app

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

i am using firebase authentication google sigin when user sigin in app. Everything is ok.

I need all emails of users almost 8000 person sigin but I didn't save email in database. now i need emails.
All emails are showing in authentication screen but how can i get all list of emails?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into the client-side SDKs of Firebase to find this information about other users than the one that is signed in. That would be a pretty big security risk.

The alternative is to use on of the [Firebase Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run, to [get a list of all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), and then store the information necessary in a place where the clients can access it.

Be sure to properly secure access to that data though, as otherwise you may inadvertently be creating the same security concern. If you're storing the data in Firebase, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started) would be the place to start to learn about that.